# Loop back the beginning of the code

Tags: java

So my code works completely; the only thing now is a very simple problem that I cannot figure out. I have to make the program loop back to the beginning if the user type restart and I cannot think how to that.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class MutantGerbil {
    public static String []foodName;
    public static int [] maxAmount;
    public static Gerbil [] gerbilAttributes;
    public static int [] consumption;

    public static void main(String [] args){

        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);


        String userInput1 = keyboard.nextLine();

        int food = Integer.parseInt(userInput1);



         foodName = new String[food]; //array of food names
         maxAmount = new int[food]; // array of max amount of food given everyday

        for (int i = 0; i < food; i++){

            System.out.println("Name of food item" + (i+1) +": "  );
            String foodType = keyboard.nextLine();

            foodName[i] = foodType;

            System.out.println("Maximum consumed per gerbil: ");
            String consumption = keyboard.nextLine();
            int consumption2 = Integer.parseInt(consumption);

            maxAmount [i] = consumption2;

        }

        System.out.println("How many gerbils are in the lab?");
        String userInput2 = keyboard.nextLine();
        int numberOfGerbils = Integer.parseInt(userInput2);
        gerbilAttributes = new Gerbil [numberOfGerbils];// Array with the gerbil attributes


        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfGerbils; i++)
        {
            consumption = new int[food]; // Array with amount of the food the gerbil eat each day
            System.out.println("Gerbil" + (i+1) + "'s" + "lab ID: ");
        String gerbilID = keyboard.nextLine();
        System.out.println("What name did the students give to "+ gerbilID);
        String gerbilName = keyboard.nextLine();
            for (int j = 0; j < food; j++)
            {
                System.out.println(gerbilID + " eats how many " + foodName[j] + " per day?");
                String gerbilComsumption = keyboard.nextLine();
                int gerbilFood = Integer.parseInt(gerbilComsumption);
                if (gerbilFood <= maxAmount[j])
                {
                    consumption[j] = gerbilFood;


                }

            }

                System.out.println("Does " + gerbilID + " bite?");
                boolean biter = keyboard.nextBoolean();
                System.out.println("Does " + gerbilID + " try to escape?");
                boolean flightRisk = keyboard.nextBoolean();
                keyboard.nextLine();
                Gerbil temp = new Gerbil (gerbilID, gerbilName, consumption, biter, flightRisk);

                gerbilAttributes [i] = temp;


        }

        boolean end1 = false;
        while (! end1){
        System.out.println("What information would you like to know");
        sortGerbilArray (gerbilAttributes);

        String userInput3 = keyboard.nextLine();


            if (userInput3.equalsIgnoreCase("average"))
            {
            String average1 = foodAverage();

                    System.out.println(average1);

            }
            if (userInput3.equalsIgnoreCase("search"))
            {
                System.out.println("Enter a Gerbil ID to search for");
                userInput3 = keyboard.nextLine();
                Gerbil findGerbil = searchForGerbil(userInput3);
                if (findGerbil == null)
                {
                    System.out.println("Error");
                }
                else {
                    String h = ("Name: " + findGerbil.getName());
                    if (findGerbil.getAttacker())
                    {
                        h+= " (will bite, ";
                    }
                        else
                        {
                            h+= " (will not bite, ";
                        }
                    if (findGerbil.getFilghtRisk())
                    {
                    h+= "will run away), "; 
                    }
                        else
                        {
                            h+= "will not run away), ";
                        }
                h+= "Food:";

                for (int i = 0; i < foodName.length; i++){
                    h+=" " + foodName[i] + "-";
                    h+= findGerbil.getConsumption2()+"/"+ maxAmount[i];
                    if (i < foodName.length-1)
                    {
                        h+=",";
                    }
                    System.out.println(h);
                }
                }
            }

            if (userInput3.equalsIgnoreCase("restart")){

            }


            if (userInput3.equalsIgnoreCase("quit"))
            {
                System.out.println("Good-bye!");
                break;
            }

        }
            }



    private static void sortGerbilArray(Gerbil[]sortGerbil){
        for (int i = 0; i < sortGerbil.length; i++){
            for (int j = 0; j < sortGerbil.length - i - 1; j++){
                if(sortGerbil[j].getID().compareToIgnoreCase(sortGerbil[j+1].getID())>0){
                    Gerbil t = sortGerbil[j];
                    sortGerbil[j] = sortGerbil[j+1];
                    sortGerbil[j+1] = t;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private static String foodAverage() 
    {
        double average = 0.0;
        double totalMaxAmount = 0;
        double totalConsumption = 0;
        String averageFood = "";

        for (int i = 0 ; i < gerbilAttributes.length;i++)
        {

            for(int j = 0; j < maxAmount.length; j++)
            {
                totalMaxAmount += maxAmount[j];
            }


                    totalConsumption += gerbilAttributes[i].getConsumption();


                    average = totalConsumption/totalMaxAmount*100;


                    averageFood += gerbilAttributes[i].getID() + "(" + gerbilAttributes[i].getName() + ")" + Math.round(average) + "%\n";

                    totalMaxAmount = 0;

                    totalConsumption = 0;
        }



        return averageFood;
    }

    private static Gerbil searchForGerbil (String x) {
        for (Gerbil l: gerbilAttributes){
            if (l.getID().equals(x)){
                return l;
            }

        }
        return null;

    }
}
```

Comment: I have if statement for the  user to perform action like search or average. I just need to know how to do the restart statement

Comment: It would be helpful to us if we didn't have to go through this much code. Can you shrink down to a prototype to better explain your requirement?

Answer (score 0):

there are two solutions.
1. wrap your code in "while" loop. but it will be difficult for you because your code is so messy :(

1. change the code as follow

   import java.util.Scanner; public class MutantGerbil {
       public static String []foodName;
       public static int [] maxAmount;
       public static Gerbil [] gerbilAttributes;
       public static int [] consumption;

   ```
   public static void main(String [] args){

       Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);


       String userInput1 = keyboard.nextLine();

       int food = Integer.parseInt(userInput1);



        foodName = new String[food]; //array of food names
        maxAmount = new int[food]; // array of max amount of food given everyday

       for (int i = 0; i < food; i++){

           System.out.println("Name of food item" + (i+1) +": "  );
           String foodType = keyboard.nextLine();

           foodName[i] = foodType;

           System.out.println("Maximum consumed per gerbil: ");
           String consumption = keyboard.nextLine();
           int consumption2 = Integer.parseInt(consumption);

           maxAmount [i] = consumption2;

       }

       System.out.println("How many gerbils are in the lab?");
       String userInput2 = keyboard.nextLine();
       int numberOfGerbils = Integer.parseInt(userInput2);
       gerbilAttributes = new Gerbil [numberOfGerbils];// Array with the gerbil attributes


       for (int i = 0; i < numberOfGerbils; i++)
       {
           consumption = new int[food]; // Array with amount of the food the gerbil eat each day
           System.out.println("Gerbil" + (i+1) + "'s" + "lab ID: ");
       String gerbilID = keyboard.nextLine();
       System.out.println("What name did the students give to "+ gerbilID);
       String gerbilName = keyboard.nextLine();
           for (int j = 0; j < food; j++)
           {
               System.out.println(gerbilID + " eats how many " + foodName[j] + " per day?");
               String gerbilComsumption = keyboard.nextLine();
               int gerbilFood = Integer.parseInt(gerbilComsumption);
               if (gerbilFood <= maxAmount[j])
               {
                   consumption[j] = gerbilFood;


               }

           }

               System.out.println("Does " + gerbilID + " bite?");
               boolean biter = keyboard.nextBoolean();
               System.out.println("Does " + gerbilID + " try to escape?");
               boolean flightRisk = keyboard.nextBoolean();
               keyboard.nextLine();
               Gerbil temp = new Gerbil (gerbilID, gerbilName, consumption, biter, flightRisk);

               gerbilAttributes [i] = temp;


       }

       boolean end1 = false;
       while (! end1){
       System.out.println("What information would you like to know");
       sortGerbilArray (gerbilAttributes);

       String userInput3 = keyboard.nextLine();


           if (userInput3.equalsIgnoreCase("average"))
           {
           String average1 = foodAverage();

                   System.out.println(average1);

           }
           if (userInput3.equalsIgnoreCase("search"))
           {
               System.out.println("Enter a Gerbil ID to search for");
               userInput3 = keyboard.nextLine();
               Gerbil findGerbil = searchForGerbil(userInput3);
               if (findGerbil == null)
               {
                   System.out.println("Error");
               }
               else {
                   String h = ("Name: " + findGerbil.getName());
                   if (findGerbil.getAttacker())
                   {
                       h+= " (will bite, ";
                   }
                       else
                       {
                           h+= " (will not bite, ";
                       }
                   if (findGerbil.getFilghtRisk())
                   {
                   h+= "will run away), "; 
                   }
                       else
                       {
                           h+= "will not run away), ";
                       }
               h+= "Food:";

               for (int i = 0; i < foodName.length; i++){
                   h+=" " + foodName[i] + "-";
                   h+= findGerbil.getConsumption2()+"/"+ maxAmount[i];
                   if (i < foodName.length-1)
                   {
                       h+=",";
                   }
                   System.out.println(h);
               }
               }
           }

           if (userInput3.equalsIgnoreCase("restart")){
                      main();
           }


           if (userInput3.equalsIgnoreCase("quit"))
           {
               System.out.println("Good-bye!");
               break;
           }

       }
           }



   private static void sortGerbilArray(Gerbil[]sortGerbil){
       for (int i = 0; i < sortGerbil.length; i++){
           for (int j = 0; j < sortGerbil.length - i - 1; j++){
               if(sortGerbil[j].getID().compareToIgnoreCase(sortGerbil[j+1].getID())>0){
                   Gerbil t = sortGerbil[j];
                   sortGerbil[j] = sortGerbil[j+1];
                   sortGerbil[j+1] = t;
               }
           }
       }
   }

   private static String foodAverage() 
   {
       double average = 0.0;
       double totalMaxAmount = 0;
       double totalConsumption = 0;
       String averageFood = "";

       for (int i = 0 ; i < gerbilAttributes.length;i++)
       {

           for(int j = 0; j < maxAmount.length; j++)
           {
               totalMaxAmount += maxAmount[j];
           }


                   totalConsumption += gerbilAttributes[i].getConsumption();


                   average = totalConsumption/totalMaxAmount*100;


                   averageFood += gerbilAttributes[i].getID() + "(" + gerbilAttributes[i].getName() + ")" + Math.round(average) + "%\n";

                   totalMaxAmount = 0;

                   totalConsumption = 0;
       }



       return averageFood;
   }

   private static Gerbil searchForGerbil (String x) {
       for (Gerbil l: gerbilAttributes){
           if (l.getID().equals(x)){
               return l;
           }

       }
       return null;

   } }
   ```

Comment: You say there are two solutions, but it looks like you only have 1.  Did you leave one out?  Or did you put 1 in there twice?  (I went to edit your answer because the code was doing weird formatting, but the source looks correct.  I guess my browser is displaying it funny.  It also shows a 1 and 2, so who knows).